# Buttons On GNOME Titlebars Keep Disappearing constantly On Ubuntu 23.10 "Mantic Minotaur"

Tags: gnome, lenovo, 23.10

I have Ubuntu 23.10 with GNOME Desktop with **Xorg**. After restarting my Lenovo Ideapad 1i, the buttons randomly disappear. It sometimes comes back but doesn't appear most of the time. I keep clicking where the title bar buttons should been, but it doesn't work. All I have to do I type `xkill` in the terminal just to close the window. This has always been so annoying with GNOME. I even tried reinstalling GNOME and restarting the GNOME shell by using this command:

```
$ gnome-shell --replace
```

Then I logged back in but this didn't even fix the no title bar buttons problem. I tried disabling all my GNOME Extensions but didn't work.

[image: The Image of the buttons missing on the titlebar]

But suprisingly some apps that have their own visual UI have their own titlebar so the titlebar buttons show up but only when the application has their own titlebar.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your issue along with your question?? It will be more clear if you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499279/edit) your question and add the image

Comment: sudo apt upgrade